Add column in WooCommerce analytics orders section
I am trying to add a column in the Woocommerce analytics -> Orders section
To do this, you need to compile an extension for WooCommerce that includes JavaScript files to display the data concretely, but I am having problems creating the extension.
This guide explains how to compile the new extension, but it seems that it does not work at the moment because wooocommerce-admin is deprecated.
try to add order item name column in woocommerce Analytics -> Orders report table (and output to csv file)
When I perform these steps when I get to "npm run build" I receive many errors of incompatibility with the versions of npm and Node.js but despite updating the versions to the recommended ones it continues to give errors of incompatibility of the versions.
So it seems there is some problem with the woocommerce-admin package
I read this guide, which refers to the guides not being updated:
https://gist.github.com/maxb2/584ea02146b42cf279fe1317d6c50d03
But following this guide I can get almost to the end but when I run "pnpm run create-extension" it gives me the error "ERR_PNPM_NO_SCRIPT Missing script: create-extension".
Can someone try to compile an extension and provide it, or give me some advice on what to do?
